# macOS: Disable promiscuous Wi-Fi scan and/or display of unwanted list of Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, tethering

I am annoyed by a display of **all** nearby Wi-Fi networks around me, when I know I am looking to connect to one among the couple of known networks.

Is there a setting to disable detection of new/unknown networks? I looked at System Preferences app → Network → Wi-Fi → Advanced, but could not find anything relevant to this requirement. It is more of a matter of reducing clutter than any major hindrance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly clarify which platform are you talking about? iOS, macOS or both?

Comment: MacOS.How to edit my question ? I was able to edit earlier but that option

Comment: Click on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/345476/edit) link. You should also be able to see edit text in grey just below the question. It's a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a setting to disable detection of new/unknown networks?

**No**.

Entering password to connect to known access points is a one time activity. May I ask, apart from aesthetics, what's your rationale for suppressing the display of the list of discovered networks?

There is no built-in setting to suppress the display of list of discovered, non-hidden Wi-Fi access points in iOS. But ever if it were there, it will only make things hard when you'll wish to connect to a new network (which, varying from person to person can still be a common use case). You'll have to manually enter the SSID and password for the access point.

Also, if it were possible, you won't be able to benefit from the [Wi-Fi password sharing](https://www.imore.com/wi-fi-password-sharing-ios-11) feature available since iOS 11 and macOS High Sierra, which lets you quickly join Wi-Fi networks your contacts present nearby are already connected to.

Comment: thanks for answering. I am looking for a setting than a permanent disable. More than aesthetics, I find my known previously network listed somewhere below and hard to locate it. There are 1/1000 odds of joining a new network frequently. It happens rarely, that I connect to new networks (for me, less than a year). For sales/frequent travellers, may be more often :-)

Comment: You would need to know what networks you don't want to see before you looked at what networks there are.  Kind of hard.  You should be going through this only once. Once done your computer should find the desired network.